# Can I write "he felt betrayal"?

Tags: grammar, writing-style

Can I write:

> [...]
>
> No, that was not it. Jack felt something at a much deeper level, *he felt betrayal*.

Or do I have to write:

> He felt *the* betrayal.

Or something like:

> He felt *the betrayal of it all*.

Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: I would prefer *he felt betrayed*. Though *he felt the betrayal* is a grammatical and idiomatic phrase, I am not sure it has the exact shade of meaning that makes sense in context. Simply *he felt betrayal* makes perfect sense, but obviously someone could quibble about whether it is actually coherent.

Comment: *He felt the betrayal* I read it that it is something very specific(an act, an event, a cause and effect, an incident...etc)  that Jack can point out. *He felt betrayed* is a kind of feeling and may not be able to pinpoint specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, I would use "He felt betrayed."

However, in your first example, "He felt betrayal." sounds perfectly correct, since the speaker said "Jack felt something..." right before it.

Adding "the" in any of the other two examples doesn't sound right.

Comment: "He felt the betrayal" doesn't sound right on its own, but "he felt the betrayal like a knife through his heart" sounds fine to me. I agree with you about using "betrayed".

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean you can't add "the" in any case. As I mentioned, using it in the other two examples didn't sound right.

Comment: So, is the following correct? " Jack felt something at a much deeper level, he felt betrayal."

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote in my answer.